# Is it possible to send HTML Email through Flash using navigateToURL()?

Tags: html, actionscript-3, email, air

I am trying to send email within an Adobe AIR app using AS3's `navigateToURL()` function. I have successfully sent over plain text, but was wondering if there is a way to set the `content-type` to `text/html` because right now it sends the HTML as brackets.

Example code:

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("mailto:me@domaincom"+"?"+"subject=Egad, an email!"+"&"+"body="+"I'm a little &lt;b&gt;teapot&lt;/b&gt; short and stout,"+"%0A"+"Here is my &lt;i&gt;handle&lt;/i&gt; and here is my spout..."));
```

It will currently output this:

> I'm a little <b>teapot</b> short and stout,
>  Here is
>   my <i>handle</i> and here is my spout...

I'm hoping to get this:

> I'm a little **teapot** short and stout,
>  Here is my
>   *handle* and here is my spout...

Thanks. :)

Comment: I think it depends on the email client.

Answer (score 0):

URLRequest has the property contentType, you tried setting it to "text/html"?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the contentType didn't work for me :(

You can try the SMTPMailer from ByteArray.org: 
http://www.bytearray.org/?p=27

That sends attachments as well as HTML emails. You'll still need your own STMP account to send through though, but still 1 step easier than making a PHP file that sends the mail for you.